# Как убрать отступ сверху? (Начинающий))

Tags: html, css, отступы

Как убрать отступ сверху?

```css
  body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 49px;
  background: #472424;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.right_nav_top li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 40px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.right_nav_top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.register {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ff7373;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.left_nav_top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.left_nav_top li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 40px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="up_nav clearfix">
    <nav>
      <ul class="right_nav_top">
        <li>
          <a href="" class="register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="imgs/79.png" alt="">
          <a href="">$465.00</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="left_nav_top">
        <li>
          <a href="">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Delivery</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Legal</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: padding-top: 20px;

Comment: Отступы есть у всех элементов `4px`. Надо обнулять у всех, а не только у `body && html`  `*{ margin: 0;padding: 0;}`

Comment: @Air непонятно, где вы увидели маргины «у всех» помимо ul (и помимо явно прописанных)

Comment: @andreymal, приглядись повнимательней....

Comment: @Air я проверил всё в инструментах разработчика — кроме явно прописанных в стилях, всё по нулям. Даже Ctrl+F по этой странице показывает 4px только в вашем комментарии (ну и теперь и в моём). В стандартных браузерных стилях маргины тоже нулевые. Куда мне приглядываться-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 49px;
    background: #472424;
}

.up_nav.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.right_nav_top {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}
ul.left_nav_top {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}


.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.right_nav_top li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 40px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.right_nav_top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.register {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ff7373;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.left_nav_top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.left_nav_top li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 40px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="up_nav clearfix">
    <nav>
      <ul class="right_nav_top">
        <li>
          <a href="" class="register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="imgs/79.png" alt="">
          <a href="">$465.00</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="left_nav_top">
        <li>
          <a href="">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Delivery</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Legal</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
  </div>
</header>
```